# Desktop icon on 1 monitor KDE5

Tags: kubuntu, kde, 17.04, plasma, desktop-icons

I have 3 monitors. I'd like my desktop icons to show on my main display monitor only, or on my second only. 
How to do this in (K)Ubuntu 17.04, KDE5?

Currently all my desktop icons appear on all 3 my monitors. 
Deleting didn't work, as it removed it on all monitors

Comment: Can you give a screenshot ?

Comment: not directly an answer I know but I usually use the 'Folder' mode in KDE to archive those things..

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it.

Right click desktop > Configure Desktop > Tab Wallpaper > Layout set to Desktop.